# Android singleton library project

Tags: android, android-library

I have a library project. That library project is shared by multiple android application. I what that library project to be singleton (same instance will be provided to all apps). Which also means once library project is instantiated it should be in memory. How can I achieve that?

Beside comments link, code snippet, tutorial and blog is highly appreciated as well. Also let me know what are the good practices for such use cases.

NOTE: of course by "instantiating library project" I mean one/some class of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this even possible? Every app in android runs in it's own VM, if i'm not wrong.

Comment: yep, every application runs in it's own dalvik vm instance. at first i misread as activities.

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda easy.

It should look something like this

```
public static class MyLib
{
     static
     { 
          System.loadLibrary("libMyLib");
     }

public native void methodA();
public native int setterA(int set);

//etc
}
```

and use it as a static lib. if you want a singleton, just add the singleton pattern to it and move the loadLibrary call to the private ctor.

Think if you really want to instantiate this class or just call it's methods statically. If you don't need an instance, this is just as good as the static block will "instantiate" it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible, because every android app runs in it's own VM,

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html

> Each process has its own virtual machine (VM), so an application's
>   code runs in isolation from other applications.

But i could be wrong off-course,

Rolf